# Is there any known pharmaceutical or chemical that could cause infertility in humans in a single dose with few or no other effects?

Tags: reproduction

Is there any known pharmaceutical or chemical that could cause infertility in humans in a single dose with few or no other effects?

The context is that a number of claims are circulating about vaccination being a "cover" for a plot to render males and/or females infertile. I claimed that it is unlikely that there is a known way to make a person infertile with a single dose of a chemical without significant side effects. However I couldn't find a source.

I'm asking as I believe it is important to have scientifically accurate responses to rumors and the like, even if they are outlandish.

Comment: People believing this sort of thing usually aren't that convinced by facts.

Comment: @BryanKrause, True, but not-yet-believers may be dissuaded from adopting the belief if contradicting facts are shown in rebuttal to the assertion.

Comment: @mgkrebbs Sure, but, given: https://xkcd.com/808/ this is a pretty insane claim. If there were some easy way to infertility with just a pill with no side effects we wouldn't be bothering with vasectomies, tubal ligation, etc. It's a losing battle to argue against things that don't have a basis: the burden of proof has to be on the claim not on the skeptics.

Comment: I would be interested to hear from someone with relevant knowledge who can lay out exactly why such a chemical is - or is not - possible. For example has any research been done into chemical alternatives to vasectomies?

Comment: yes, chemical castration, or chemical sterilisation! They generally have many side effects. The pill makes millions of female temporarily "infertile" every day. I am not sure how important this question is to the claim though. The simple counterfactual surely is enough? I have had many vaccine and am not infertile. Billions of vaccinations given a year. And in the developed world coverage of upwards of 90% for most vaccines. Wouldn't 90% of the developed world then be infertile?

Comment: It's hard to understand why, if such a chemical existed and was available at a price cheap enough to be used in mass vaccinations, it would not be available commercially as a less expensive alternative to vasectomy or tubal ligation.

Comment: @reubenmcg but are any of those chemical methods permanently effective in a single dose? My understanding is that they're not?

Comment: @jamesqf exactly.

Comment: Absence of evidence... years or reading science publications I haven't heard of any. If there was a single dose infertility drug with few side effects this sure would be big, big news. Getting the influential people onside before vaccination would be good, including vaccinating oneself.

Comment: ". If there was a single dose infertility drug with few side effects this sure would be big, big news. "  -- can you add an answer listing publications where that information would be expected to appear?